# Unfinished string litteral simplexml

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

It got this line using xpath with error :

**A PHP Error was encountered**

**Severity: Warning**

**Message: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Unfinished literal**

**Filename: requete_oracle/Accueil.php**

**Line Number: 345**

This is my line :

```
$string = $sharedStrings->xpath("//*[local-name()='t' and .= '".(string)$data."']");
```

local-name is because of namespace problems.

It don't know where is the problem..

Thank you for help !

Comment: Please show the complete error message with line number, and then indicate which line of code is causing the error to be thrown

Comment: The line from the question does not trigger the error, see:https://eval.in/742454 It might be triggered from the previous line or because of the value in `$data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for me :

```
$string = $sharedStrings->xpath('//*[local-name() = "t" and .= "{$data}"]');
```